# Parallel Array for State and Capital Guess Game

Tags: java, arrays

I tried to get the output that asks random states and capitals, but my output always ask "what is the capital of Alabama?" and then displays error for the next line. How can I make it to ask a ransom state and capital correctly?

```
public static void main (String args [])throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input= null;
    Scanner file=null;
    try
    { input= new Scanner(System.in);
      file= new Scanner (new File ("capitals.txt"));

      while (file.hasNext()){
          String[] myString = file.next().split (",");
          System.out.println(String.format ("What is the capital of %s?", myString[0]));
          System.out.println(input.next().equals(myString[1]));

      }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fe){
    }
    finally {
       file.close();
       input.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: By the way, my import and class are    import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class StateCapitalLookup {

Comment: where are the random numbers ? You aren't generating the index

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any randomness in your code. These are the steps (according to what you have currently):

1. Read the states and capitals from your text file.
2. Store them in String array(s).
3. Generate a random number from 0 to size of array-1.
4. use that random number as the index of your String array.

**A simplified example:**

```
Random rnd = new Random();
String[] capitals = readFromFile();
int x = rnd.nextInt(capitals.length);
System.out.println(String.format ("What is the capital of %s?", capitals[x]));
```